# trying to loop through array and pass values to php cURL request

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Hello I have a successful cURL request that returns the 8 largest cities in a country including the city name, country code, latitude and longitude (`$largeCities['records']`). What I then want to do is loop through that array and pass the latitude, longitude and country code of each city to a new cURL routine (geonames findNearbyWikipedia api) and return that data to use in my JavaScript. I'm wondering if this is possible and if so where am I going wrong. Currently when I run the $.ajax request on my php file I'm just getting an empty array `cityCluster: Array(0)`

relevent php code:

```
//large cities in country
    $url='https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=geonames-all-cities-with-a-population-1000&q=&rows=8&sort=population&facet=timezone&facet=country&refine.country_code='. $countryCodeA2;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $largeCities = json_decode($result,true);
    $output['data']['largeCities'] = $largeCities['records'];

    foreach ($largeCities['records'] as $key => $value) {
        $cityLat = $value['geometry']['coordinates'][0];
        $cityLng = $value['geometry']['coordinates'][1];
        $countryCodeISO2 = $value['fields']['country_code'];
   
            //wiki cities clusters
            $url='http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyWikipediaJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $cityLat . '&lng=' . $cityLng . '&country='. $countryCodeISO2 .'&maxRows=15&username=' . $geoUserName . '&style=full';
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

            $result=curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $cityCluster = json_decode($result,true);

    };

    //output status
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['executedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";

    $output['data']['cityCluster'] = $cityCluster['geonames'];
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Hint: You're overwriting the same variable inside the `foreach` loop. Check this line `$cityCluster = json_decode($result,true);`

Comment: You're overwriting the value of $cityCluster each time you pass through the loop, rather than appending to an array. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks everyone, So I added  ```$data = array();``` on the line before my foreach loop and inside the loop I added/ chaged to ```$cityCluster = json_decode($result,false); array_push($data, $cityCluster);``` and finally outside the loop ```$output['data']['cityCluster'] = $data;``` also removed ```header('Content-Type: application/json');``` Now I do get 7 empty arrays and 1 array with one object inside (should have 15). Progress at least :) Still not sure how to get fully working though.

Comment: Actually it does work! I just had my longitude and latitude inverted like a dummy. THANK YOU!